# Is it possible to configure a Jenkins slave node and master on the same system? When I configured the slave node on my PC

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to configure a Jenkins slave node and master on the same system?

When I configured the slave node on my PC, I was not able open the Jenkins console. It would show an error message like below...

```
[!] Error

org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activeDirectory': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com4j.ExecutionException: com4j.ComException: 8007054b Failed to MkParseDisplayName : The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted. : .\com4j.cpp:217
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:246)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:43)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:904)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:804)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:77)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$2.run(WebAppMain.java:214)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activeDirectory': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com4j.ExecutionException: com4j.ComException: 8007054b Failed to MkParseDisplayName : The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted. : .\com4j.cpp:217
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at hudson.util.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:94)
    at hudson.util.spring.BeanBuilder.createApplicationContext(BeanBuilder.java:388)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.createSecurityComponents(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:131)
    at hudson.security.SecurityRealm.getSecurityComponents(SecurityRealm.java:398)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.reset(HudsonFilter.java:134)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.setSecurityRealm(Jenkins.java:2030)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$19.run(Jenkins.java:2598)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:146)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:893)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com4j.ExecutionException: com4j.ComException: 8007054b Failed to MkParseDisplayName : The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted. : .\com4j.cpp:217
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: com4j.ExecutionException: com4j.ComException: 8007054b Failed to MkParseDisplayName : The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted. : .\com4j.cpp:217
    at com4j.ComThread.execute(ComThread.java:203)
    at com4j.Task.execute(Task.java:25)
    at com4j.COM4J.getObject(COM4J.java:256)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.<init>(ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: com4j.ComException: 8007054b Failed to MkParseDisplayName : The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted. : .\com4j.cpp:217
    at com4j.Native.getObject(Native Method)
    at com4j.COM4J$GetObjectTask.call(COM4J.java:277)
    at com4j.COM4J$GetObjectTask.call(COM4J.java:265)
    at com4j.Task.invoke(Task.java:51)
    at com4j.ComThread.run0(ComThread.java:153)
    at com4j.ComThread.run(ComThread.java:134)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error message points to a configuration problem in the main Jenkins installation. Turn off, or remove, the ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider plugin. For help removing the plugin, see *[How do I uninstall a plugin from Jenkins (Hudson)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965235/how-to-uninstall-a-plugin-from-jenkins-hudson)*.